# Sorting a text file with strings and digits on each line - Python 3

Tags: list, sorting, python-3.x, text-files

I have a text file I made with some runners and their race times in which looks like this:

```
Dylan , 3.6
Tom , 4.2
Jack , 1.4
Dave , 8.8
Mick , 5.2
John , 11.3
Matt , 7.6
Ben , 9.7
Joe , 3.9
Chris , 3.3
```

I have a new line for each new race participant and their race time after a comma.

How can I sort this text file so the person with the fastest time is at the top.
The code I used to generate the test file looks like this:

```
def runnerData():
    thefile = open("race.txt" , "w")
    names = ["Dylan" , "Tom" , "Jack" , "Dave" , "Mick" , "John" , "Matt" , "Ben" , "Joe" , "Chris"]
    times = ["3.6" , "4.2" , "1.4" , "8.8" , "5.2" , "11.3" , "7.6" , "9.7" , "3.9" , "3.3"]
    zipped = zip(names, times)
    for aname,atime in zipped:
        thefile.write("%s , %s\n" %(aname,atime))

runnerData()
```

I have only just started using Python and am not familiar with a lot of it - still learning! :)

Thanks.

EDIT:

The code I used to generate the file ok and i'm happy it works - The task I have been set is to write a new file using the text file I have generated to display the winner of the race.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort your `zipped` list based on second element,you can use [*`sorted()`*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function with a proper `key` :

```
from operator import itemgetter
def runnerData():
    thefile = open("race.txt" , "w")
    names = ["Dylan" , "Tom" , "Jack" , "Dave" , "Mick" , "John" , "Matt" , "Ben" , "Joe" , "Chris"]
    times = ["3.6" , "4.2" , "1.4" , "8.8" , "5.2" , "11.3" , "7.6" , "9.7" , "3.9" , "3.3"]
    zipped = zip(names, times)
    for aname,atime in sorted(zipped,key=float(itemgetter(1)),reverse=True):
            thefile.write("%s , %s\n" %(aname,atime))

runnerData()
```

And if you read the preceding file you can do :

```
l=[]
for line in open('your_file'):
   l.append(line.split(','))
```

So the `l` would be :

```
[['Dylan ', ' 3.6'], ['Tom ', ' 4.2'], ['Jack ', ' 1.4'], ['Dave ', ' 8.8'], ['Mick ', ' 5.2'], ['John ', ' 11.3'], ['Matt ', ' 7.6'], ['Ben ', ' 9.7'], ['Joe ', ' 3.9'], ['Chris ', ' 3.3']]
```

then you can use the preceding `sorted()` function to sort your list :

```
sorted(l,key=float(itemgetter(1)),reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) The code I included above my teacher is happy with - what I need to do is write a new python file that can read the textfile and sort it without having the data already sorted for me.

Comment: Thanks again - I'm still new to this and struggling to understand :S Is there any way I can take my original file I wrote and write a new file that will sort the data, line by line how it is? Due to my lack of understanding I didn't know whether your last edit would work for my original file, Sorry :(

Comment: @GeorgeWhitlow did you tried my code? `for line in open('your_file'):` doesn't read the new line character!!!